# How to get the return type of a function

Tags: actionscript-3, reflection

It doesn't appear to be possible to get the return type of a function. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`describeType()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29) does it if the function you need is a public class member